# My page does not load after adding google chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api, google-visualization

I want to display data table + google chart on same page after a ajax call. I get numberOfStudents and numberOfFamiliesUsingApp from ajax call which I am  passing to google chart. When I try below code page just does not show up. Inside developer tool I keep seeing 'Buffer Usage' but nothing is displayed.

```
<script src='assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var classId = "<s:property value="classId"/>" ;
    var schoolId = "<s:property value="schoolId"/>" ;
    var tableData = [];
    var numberOfStudents = 0;
    var numberOfFamiliesUsingApp = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $.getJSON( "json1/getJSONParentResult.json?schoolId="+schoolId+"&classId="+classId, function( data ) {
        tableData = data.data;
        numberOfStudents = data.numberOfStudents;
        numberOfFamiliesUsingApp = data.numberOfFamiliesUsingApp;

        //Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

       function drawChart() {

          // Create the data table.
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         data.addColumn('string', 'Total');
         data.addColumn('number', 'Usage');
         //replace the values with javascript variables which are set after ajax call  
         data.addRows([
            ['Total Students', numberOfStudents],
            ['Total Usage', numberOfFamiliesUsingApp]
         ]);

         // Set chart options
         var options = {'title':'School Rush Activities',
                     'width':500,
                     'height':400};

         // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
         var chart = new       google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
         chart.draw(data, options);
       }            

       $('#example').dataTable( {
         "bPaginate": true,
         "bProcessing": true,
         "bServerSide": false,
         "iDisplayLength": 100,
         "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
         "aaData": tableData
       } );
    });
} );
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Login</th>
            <th>Student LastName</th>
            <th>Student FirstName</th>
            <th>Account Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

If I comment google chart code then data table displays properly. Unable to understand what is going wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide us with your JSON?

Comment: {"data":[[null,"Datey","Kabir","2220000000"],[null,"Datey","Zara","2220000000"],[null,"Rao","Aditya","4444444444"]],"numberOfStudents":10,"numberOfFamiliesUsingApp":8}

Answer (score 0):

Your script has a syntax error, because you haven't escaped your strings properly. These lines are the cause of this:

```
var classId = "<s:property value="classId"/>";
var schoolId = "<s:property value="schoolId"/>";
```

You can either escape the `"` with a backslash, or use a `'`. like so:

```
var classId = "<s:property value=\"classId\"/>";
var schoolId = '<s:property value="schoolId" />';
```

(notice how the colorization of the code makes this incredibly clear at a glance. If you aren't already, using a [good](http://www.sublimetext.com/) [text editor](https://atom.io/) will help you avoid similar issues in the future)

Comment: Still the same issue. The only time it worked when I put google chart in separate script tag. But then sometimes I do get correct result sometimes I don't get result. I have to refresh 2-3 times.

Comment: @user2869612 are you seeing any errors in the dev console? (Ctrl+Shift+J)

Comment: No errors on console except 'buffer usage'. Chart would come up (may be after 2-3 refresh) If I move google chart in a separate tag

Comment: Instead of google chart I switched to Chart.js and now it is picking up my dynamic data properly and showing me correct result. I know this is not a solution but an alternative. For the time being this worked for me.

Comment: @user2869612 wait, I thought the problem was that dataTables wouldn't load... With the google maps code, Is that still happening?

Comment: 1) If I insert google chart code inside $.getJSON success callback handler page does not load. - The code for which I have posted above 2) If I remove google chart code then page loads properly. 3) If I put google chart code in separate script tab (outside $.getJSON success handler) then datatable loads. After 2-3 refresh even google chart loads. 4)If I use Chart.js  then everything works fine.